# Error parsing JSON in my Android app?

Tags: android, json

I have string json like this :

```
{
  "listResult": {
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "629047db-66d9-4986-ba3f-c75554198138",
        "thumbnail": "http://maya-wdv-01.r.worldssl.net/39aa32db-6f50-4da1-8fd5-a5b001135b98/629047db-66d9-4986-ba3f-c75554198138/8cb69c17-0fdb-454c-bfb5-a5b9001a9d59.jpg"
      },
      {
        "id": "fa872dc8-d2b3-4815-92ef-d90e903bc3d8",
        "thumbnail": "http://maya-wdv-01.r.worldssl.net/39aa32db-6f50-4da1-8fd5-a5b001135b98/fa872dc8-d2b3-4815-92ef-d90e903bc3d8/c510c24f-5bfd-4a64-8851-a5b90017a38d.jpg"
      }
    ],
    "totalItems": 34,
    "pageSize": 5,
    "pageNumber": 1,
    "totalPages": 7,
    "searchTerm": null
  }
}
```

I Try Parsing with code :

```
try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
            String listResult = json.getString(Variabel.listResult);
            JSONArray items_obj = json.getJSONArray(Variabel.items);
            int jumlah_list_data = items_obj.length();
            if (jumlah_list_data > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < jumlah_list_data; i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = items_obj.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = obj.getString(Variabel.id);
                    String thumbnail = obj.getString(Variabel.thumbnail);

                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But I getting Error :

> org.json.JSONException: No value for items

So how to solve it ? sorry for my English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
 String listResult = json.getString(Variabel.listResult);               
 JSONArray items_obj = json.getJSONArray(Variabel.items);
```

you should have:

```
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
  JSONObject listResult = json.getJSONObject(Variabel.listResult);
  JSONArray items_obj = listResult.getJSONArray(Variabel.items);
```

Answer (score 2):

Accordingly to the json you posted, items is direct child of `listResult`, so you have to use the `JSONObject` with key `listResult` to retrieve it. Change

```
  JSONArray items_obj = json.getJSONArray(Variabel.items);
```

with

```
  JSONArray items_obj = listResult.getJSONArray(Variabel.items);
```